# Blog is a single webpage that gets data asyncronously, searchable by Search Engines?

Tags: web-development, websites, search-engine

I have created a blog for a friend.

I have heavily designed it around jQuery's `$.ajax()` function and as a result it is only a single webpage asynchronously gets its data (title, article, relative image paths, etc.) from the database.

To navigate, a visitor can do the following:

- Type on a given *search* `<input>`, site will give buttons, and then when a button is pressed, show the data asynchronously to the document area of the site
- Press on the default buttons, and the page will load the data asynchronously to the document area of the site

Being a single page website that does all this, I don't utilize the URL at all. All transfer of data is via POST.

My problem is this: will the page's CONTENTS, if ever published online, be searchable by search engines?

By contents I mean all of the sites available titles, written articles, comments, etc. be searchable if I code it in this manner?

A fellow programmer criticized me for this because, according to him I should have instead created an application that created the **whole HTML files** for the site whenever there are new articles are written, and use URL for navigation so google and other search engines can maximize searching. Is this true?

*by single page, I meant that the viewer can visit a single webpage of the site alone, and does not have to go anywhere else. There are other pages as well:

- For the admin to write new articles, there is a separate single webpage that performs *CRUD* operations.
- I also have a webpage that produces JSON when you POST to it.

Comment: What can I do to improve the question, downvoter?

Comment: SEO aside, are you saying you can't share a link to a specific article? That seems like a basic requirement for a blog, that I can do this http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/May/14/eleanor-rigbot.html instead of saying "visit my blog and search for the Beatles". You should think about the costs and benefits of SPAs vs. MPAs and how those pros and cons map to the specific kind of site you're building.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I haven't thought about sharing links, my bad. But what if I implement a GET? (www.myblog.com?article=thisArticle), will that be the same?

Comment: @jonrsharpe if yes, how will that factor in the SEO?

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there on SPA SEO if you decide to continue on this path.

Comment: Any reasons you're not just using already-available blogging software like Wordpres, Drupal, or Squarespace?

Comment: @LieRyan just a hobby project and I wanted to practice, but yeah they do say that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I have read from [Pawel Skolski](https://neoteric.eu/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application?utm_source=medium.com&utm_medium=social&utm_content=neo&utm_campaign=blog) of Neoteric and from [uxpin](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/single-page-vs-multi-page-ui-design-pros-cons/) about Single Page applications and Multiple Page Applications.

In summary, they state that MPAs are better for what I am trying to achieve, as each page can be optimized with keywords for SEO.

In case of blogs, where each Article is preferably able to be found by search engines, this is the way to go.

The root problem stems from a lack of understanding how Google(and most other) search engines work.

Doing a lot of [reading](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) about how googlebot works now, I now understand that I have to follow [Progressive Enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement#Core_principles) **regardless** if it's a blog, or any other site:

- Basic content should be accessible to all web browsers (*So far my content can be produced in IE 9. I think it will have trouble in [IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206782/ajax-call-not-working-in-ie8)* )
- Basic functionality should be accessible to all web browsers (*same as above*)
- Sparse, semantic markup contains all content
- Enhanced layout is provided by externally linked CSS (no problem here)
- Enhanced behavior is provided by unobtrusive, externally linked JavaScript
  (*that's the problem right there, my SPA site DEPENDS on javascript to produce the content.*)
- End-user web browser preferences are respected (*I have been doing it wrong. Mine does the ff: if javascript is turned off ask them to turn it on, if browser is IE, recommend them to use Chrome, Safari or Firefox instead.*)

  Overall, I will have to rewrite my SPA site into a hybrid that will cater above principles.